# Create Custom displaying Activity for android

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I want this kind of `translucent` `activity/fragment` for `android` any help would be appreciated

Android activity/fragment overlapping here just like this one:

[image]

Comment: well just add a background image & simply blurrify it!

Comment: you are not understanding it i mean the background image which is blurry is the activity already opened and that conversation activity is overlapped in it

Comment: well then simply try setting the windowBackground of the conversation Activity as transparent

Comment: and what about that blurry effect ??

Comment: you cannot show 2 activities at once, therefore you should follow the steps in my first comment, simply add a blurred image background to the "root element" of the layout & it sould work... as long as the text color is white, it should work ;)

Comment: hey DarShan i have just updated the link . if you take a closer look on that pop up fragment or something its overlapped the background text is still showing up

Comment: its an AlertDialog with semi translarent background... you can set the background of an AlertDialog from it's Builder class... e.g AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this); builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#Your Semi Transparent RGB Color Value")));

Comment: ya this app has been updated but very in the beginning it was covering the hole screen

Answer (score 1):

use this style for your app :

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoBackGround">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

then set the blur and transparent background on the activity

Comment: how to make it blur?? now

Comment: @Roasted_Ginger use Picasso library and trasparent image or set the activity backgrond and use fragment with this color as #80000000 background